# Intel Sky Lake Graphics Card - Random Black/Blank Screens on external screen

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, i915

I'm having an issue where the screen randomly goes blank/black while I'm using the system. The blank does not appear to be associated with screen refreshes or anything specific. It happened about 3 times while writing this simple paragraph, but sometimes doesn't happen for tens of minutes of usage. The screen blanks ONLY happen on external monitors (HDMI from the side ports of the laptop, and Display port from the laptop dock). When I have two monitors connected via display port, the only screen that goes black is the one with my cursor on it.

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu with Cinnamon as my desktop. I assume the somewhat new Intel Sky Lake integrated may be the issue after reading other threads.

Here's my info:

Laptop

> HP EliteBook Folio 1040 G2

sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display               
description: VGA compatible controller

product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 07
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_mastercap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:278 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

uname -a

```
Linux <<redacted>> 4.5.1-040501-generic #201604121331 SMP Tue Apr 12 17:33:29 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a notebook with the exact same video device, it is a Lenovo Ideapad 310. Soon after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it, I noticed it had many issues: monitors not being properly detected, wireless and bluetooth failures, USB 3.0 port unable to eject devices, lid not being understood, well, the problems of a new system not being properly supported.

To solve most of them (unless the USB 3.0 problem), I have installed the **linux-generic-hwe-16.04** package. Before installing the package, the kernel the computer had was 4.4.0.xx, then it started using the 4.8.0.xx, which added more support to Skylake systems.

However, I needed to go further due to the USB 3.0 problem, so I use the [kernel from here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). I don't recommend you to install kernels from there, unless if there are significant problems the stable kernels don't solve.

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, I would recommend to update the kernel to version 4.8.0.xx, as available on repositories as **linux-generic-hwe-16.04**, which was enough to stop monitor issues.

I am using a external monitor connected to a VGA port (its a Display Port for the processor, but the connection is VGA) now, and I can use its HDMI to connect to my TV, being able to see Full HD media with no problem.

If this don't solve, you could try to use another desktop to test if Cinnamon is causing the problems. The **xfwm4** of Xubuntu is being flawless to me, even with the 4.4.0.xx kernel it was.

**uname -a**

```
Linux ideapad 4.10.4-041004-generic #201703180831 SMP Sat Mar 18 12:34:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```